# SecurityContextHolder.getContext() not working in AspectJ class

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop

I created an @Aspect class and trying to get the principal object like..

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() .getPrincipal()
```

inside my aspect class but I am getting null pointer. No context is available in my aspect.Any pointers.?

Comment: Can you show your security xml? And stack trace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SecurityContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) associates a given SecurityContext with the current execution thread. As aspect intercepts method on separate thread(Not very sure), ***So you may need to change the  security context holder strategy***. As [SecurityContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) provides a series of static methods that delegate to an instance of [SecurityContextHolderStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolderStrategy.html). The purpose of [SecurityContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) is to provide a convenient way to specify the strategy that should be used for a given JVM.

If no strategy is defined [SecurityContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) class will default to using MODE_THREADLOCAL.

**So you need to change the strategy to MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL.**

There are two ways to specify the desired strategy mode. The first is to specify it via the *system property* keyed on SYSTEM_PROPERTY. The second is to call *setStrategyName(String)* **[before using the class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html)**.

In Spring, you need to define a bean in application context as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass"><value>org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder</value></property>
    <property name="targetMethod"><value>setStrategyName</value></property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks alot.Good stuffl

Comment: How can i adapt this answer on a programatically Configuration with @Bean ?

Answer (score 2):

This could happen in case the aspect is executed...

1. ...on a non-servlet thread, i.e. some background thread or one that has been started during request processing. In the latter case you can solve the problem by configuring the `SecurityContextHolder` to store the context in an *inheritable* `ThreadLocal` which spawned threads can access as well (see the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) for details).
2. ...before the request gets authenticated by the responsible security filters. Enable logging for security classes, or set up some breakpoints for a debug session to check if this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that this code was covered by spring security filter chain.

`SecurityContextHolder` will be populated by one of Spring Security filters (`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`). So if security filter chain is not fired for current request / thread then `SecurityContextHolder` is empty. Make a brakepoint in `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(...)` method. If it is not fired then make appropriate changes in your security xml file.

Comment: How can I do this.Can you please share some steps as to how to configure this?

Comment: Please show your security xml file. Without your conf it will be quite difficult to tell something specific.

Comment: I can email you the xml file or tell me any other way of sending it.It is too long to fit in here

Comment: Post only your `<http>...</http>` tag and the URL used to call your pointcut.

Comment: I guess I am going absolutely wrong .I do not have any such thing like you demanded in my xml files. Can you please post a sample configuration?Or point me to any URL...really appreciate your quick responses.

Comment: [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal) is example from the official documentation.

Comment: <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <intercept-url pattern="/portals*" method="PUT" access="hasAnyRole('role_admin','role_manager')" />
       <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                    authentication-failure-handler-ref="customSpecialPageHandler"
                    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
<custom-filter before="ANONYMOUS_FILTER" ref="portal_anonymousFilter"/>
<logout success-handler-ref="customSpecialPageHandler"/></http>

Comment: And the URL that was called?